# How can I filter out unique results from grep output?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

In linux, I can grep a string from a file using `grep mySearchString myFile.txt`.
How can I only get the result which are unique?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) and [`uniq`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq) utilities.

example:

```
[john@awesome ~]$ echo -e "test\ntest\ntest\nanother test\ntest"
test
test
test
another test
test
[john@awesome ~]$ echo -e "test\ntest\ntest\nanother test\ntest" | sort | uniq
another test
test
```

depending on the data you may want to utilize some of the switches as well.

Comment: @John T - I would recommend to use `sort` before `uniq` in case the data are not ordered. Otherwise `uniq` won't completely work.

Comment: t now I can upvote ! You also helped me writing others scripts here ;)

Comment: Use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`. It saves a process, reduces the total I/O, and reduces the total number of comparisons that have to be made.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen You should make that comment an answer as it's a better solution then the current given answer

Answer (score 18):

You can use:

```
grep -rohP "(mySearchString)" . | sort -u
```

-r: recursive

-o: only print matching part of the text

-h: don't print filenames

-P: Perl style regex (you may use -E instead depending on your case)

`sort -u` is better than `sort | uniq`, as @Chris Johnsen pointed out.

Comment: `sort` `-R` flag would use a random "sort" that only groups unique elements without actually sorting. I haven't benchmarked it, but it could be faster.